# GlusterFS Client - Check if sync finished

Tags: glusterfs

I want to use GlusterFS with my web server. Before I bring a new web server instance online in the load balancer, I was wondering if there's a way to check if the files are done syncing? For example, if I have 50,000 files on the Gluster Server, is there a way to check programmatically that all 50,000 are on the new instance?

Also, what happens if a request for file happens before the file is on the new instance? As an example, if a web server request is example.com/test.html and test.html hadn't transferred yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The command as below is to check if GlusterFS is syncing data background:

```
gluster volume heal <volume_name> info
```

It means that GlusterFS is syncing data background if number of entries is not zero.

Please note that this command doesn't do any work for distributed volume.

Thanks.